# Empty message with Formt in MODx

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, formit

Here is my code of send-page:

```
<p>[[!FormIt?
&hooks=`email,FormItLog,spam,emailUser,redirect`
&emailTo=`heash94@gmail.com`
&emailSubject=`[[+subject]]`
&emailFromName=`[[+name]]`
&emailTpl=`ContactTpl`
&redirectTo=`62` ]]</p>

<div>[[+fi.error.error_message]]</div>
<form action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="nospam:blank" value="" />
<div>
    <label for="name">Name: </label> <input id="name" type="text" name="name:required" value="[[+fi.name]]" /> <span>[[+fi.error.name]]</span>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="name">Email: </label> <input id="email" type="text" name="email:email:required" value="[[+fi.email]]" /> <span>[[+fi.error.email]]</span></div>
<div>
    <label for="subject">Theme: </label> <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject:required:stripTags" value="[[+fi.subject]]" /> <span>[[+fi.error.subject]]</span></div>
<div>
    <label for="message">Text: </label><span>[[+fi.error.message]]</span> <br /> <textarea id="message" name="message:required:stripTags" rows="7" cols="55">[[+fi.message]]</textarea></div>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Отправить" /></div>
</form>
```

I tried many examples, but they send to my email empty messages.

Here is my reciver-page code:

```
This message [[+name]] ([[+email]]) was sand with callback form: 
[[+message]]
```

But in response I have only "This message () was sent with callback form: ".
Modx Revolution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like modx is not seeing the name="email:email:required" as 'email' - put your CSS/JS validation in another attribute & also use the &validate attribute for the formit call.